# Auto update user position based on total mark with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update a table with user positions based on their total mark with this query

```
$default='0';

mysql_select_db($database_catchapp, $catchapp);
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE competitors SET position= $default= ($default+1) ORDER BY score DESC" );
$Result= mysql_query($updateSQL, $db) or die(mysql_error());
```

But when I execute it updates the positions with 0 from the first record to the last.
What I'm expecting is it should update the positions based on total score from `1` to last record

Answer (score 0):

This isn't information you insert into a database, this is information you use a database to calculate and retrieve.

Every competitor already has a score entered into the database, if you try and save their positions then you need to recalculate that every time a score changes and resave it all.

It's pointless anyway because listing them by position is just a way of sorting the data, and sorting data is something computers are good at.

If you run `SELECT * FROM competitors ORDER BY score DESC` you will get the results by rank. If you need a ran column too then try this:

`SET @rank = 0;
SELECT *, (SELECT @rank:=@rank + 1) AS rank FROM competitors ORDER BY score DESC`

Comment: I know I can get it with a select statement easily but I want to do it like how is in the question

Comment: I don't understand why you would ever need to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$default='0';
```

is declared as string.

Make it it like this:

```
$default=0;
mysql_select_db($database_catchapp, $catchapp);
$default= ($default+1) ;
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE competitors SET position= $default ORDER BY score DESC" );
```